# Dynamically loading div's through Javascript does not work with onload

Tags: javascript, html

I am making use of a localstorage to store all my information about bugs and other things such as users. I want to loop through my localstorage and create a div for each specific record (records that contain keys with "Bug" in them) so I created this:
[Function that dynamically adds div's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MClgf.jpg)

Then I want to make it so it runs this function when the webpage loads so I do this in my html file:
[Running the function when the webpage loads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgjOq.jpg)

But then it does not insert my div's, when I test the function on a button's onclick event it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Please don't post images of code.

Comment: Paste your code here as text, not as images.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

Your windows.load function should be separate, in it's own script tag.

```
<Script type="text/javascript"> 
window.load = function(){ LoadBugs; }; 
</script>
```

and the script reference added like this:

```
<script src="processes.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `src` attribute from the `script` tag.
Because the `script` tag has a `src` attribute your code is ignored.

Comment: How would I link my javascript file without a src? I'm new to this

Comment: Add a second script tag to link your javascript file.